# Unix - Using pipe inside watch command (Count connections groupped by state)

Tags: unix, pipe, netstat

I am trying to count the amount of connections while groupping them by their 'state'.

This command achieve that goal :

```
netstat -ant | awk '{ print $6}' | sort | uniq -c
```

which provide an output that looks like that :

```
  4 CLOSE_WAIT
  1 established)
127 ESTABLISHED
  1 Foreign
  2 LAST_ACK
 39 LISTEN
  9 TIME_WAIT
```

I am trying to combine my command with the `watch` command like that :

```
watch -n 1 "netstat -ant | awk '{ print $6}' | sort | uniq -c"
```

But, the output is just of the `netstat -ant` command (and not the last output of the pipe).

How can I use that complex command with `watch` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
watch -n1 "netstat -ant | awk '{ print \$6}' | sort | uniq -c"
```

You're passing a double quoted string that happens to contain single quotes. Inside a double quoted string, `$`s meant as literal `$`s must be escaped (`$6` => `\$6`). 
When you don't escape it, `watch` will likely receive

```
"netstat -ant | awk '{ print }' | sort | uniq -c"
```

(as `$6` is likely to be unset), which would explain the output you're getting (`awk '{ print }'` in a pipeline is essentially a no-op, like `cat`).